# Why don't mathematicians introduce intuition behind concepts as physicists do?

Tags: proof-writing, physics, mathematical-physics, education, philosophy

First of all please don't be angry - if anyone might be - and thoughtlessly downvote this post. I'll make it clear that I'm not here to criticise mathematicians - but rather to understand.

I understand the importance and significance of accurate statements of definitions and theorems and their respective proofs.

I read some mathematical methods in physics books and felt that they lack systematic approaches to concepts. They are more like well-written novels with a good plot.

So I always refer to some (relatively) more rigorous books that discuss each area of mathematical methods in more detail. These are usually books with titles *subject name + "with applications"* or something like that.

But at the same time, I felt that all of these *proper* maths books only contain, from the beginning till the end, definition - theorem - example - proof - remark kind of approach. Honestly, I find them very boring yet solidly written.

I saw maths department professors take the identical approach in their classes. Here comes what I think is a more serious problem - such ways of teaching have no intuition.

I'll compare two different ways of explaining a single concept of differentiation.

The first way I would do is to introduce the $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition of a derivative and provide proofs of various theorems about it - like linearity, product rule, quotient rule, chain rule and so on.

The second way I would do is to initially very informally introduce the notion of tangent vector, differential forms $dx, dy$, linear approximation and Taylor expansion. And then talk about how it is historically originated from Newton's study of mechanics, and how it is contemporarily applied to various optimisation problems. And then start dealing with the basic proofs of facts, perhaps by exploiting $\varepsilon-\delta$.

I don't see how the first way of teaching has any pedagogical advantage which is how mathematicians are doing mathematics. It definitely trains you to have a rigorous understanding. However, it does not only de-motivate students but also stops them from taking the intuitions out of it.

So, my questions come.

1. How come mathematicians have intuitions though? I felt that I would never be able to have an intuitive understanding if this was the only way in which I was taught mathematics.
2. Why do mathematicians hate to include intuitions? To phrase it a bit more offensively, what will then be the point of countless repetitions of theorems and proofs if there's no motivation? Why not nicely mix intuition and rigorousness?

Comment: Intuition is the starting point, form Euclid on; then intuition is "rigorized" through definition and axioms.

Comment: Some interesting points, however probably not the right place to post such questions. Also you should reformulate some points. Like *Honestly, they are very boring yet solidly written.* Should be *I feel they are really boring yet solidly written*. I don't feel proper math books boring! Also, intuitions are coming with practice and studying many, many, many... examples. Like probably in all fields. Picasso has not done cubism paintings from the start!

Comment: "How come mathematicians have intuitions ?" We all "have intuitions", but intuition is also "training": our knowledge of natural number is **not** based on Peano's axioms, but on the training received in elementary schools. That training provides us with the basic "intuition" about the succession of natural numbers and the relevant operations.

Comment: "I felt that all of these proper maths books only contain, from the beginning till the end, definition - theorem - example - proof - remark kind of approach." -- A beautiful thing!

Comment: It's getting late here, so I'll leave this as just a short comment. When you *learn* math you need all the background, insight and intuition behind each step. A good teacher will provide that. Later in (math) life, you may need to revisit certain parts in the most rigorous, concise formulation. A good reference book will provide that. A teacher who just recites reference material is not doing the job they were meant for.

Comment: *"Why do mathematicians hate to include intuitions"* Mathematicians don't hate intuitions. But intuitions may be misleading... For example, it was almost a given for centuries that maps maybe non differentiable at some points but non at every points. Until such a strange beast was given at the end of the 19th century.

Comment: I'll (gently) counter-attack: mathematicians are the only ones with a healthy relationship to intuitions: they don't hate them, they have them and use them like every human being, but they just don't trust them. And that's exactly how it should be. It is in fact a more common occurrence to see scientists (like physicists, since you mention them), even quite famous ones, starting to trust a little too much their intuitions because of a growing (and misplaced) overconfidence in their own abilities, especially in the later stages of their careers.

Comment: @user3733558 Aha... that's very convincing. I haven't thought about that aspect. So to what (rough) degree do you think physics undergrads and researchers, respectively, have to know about rigorous maths to also try to maintain a healthy relationship with intuitions? Could you please elaborate with some examples?

Comment: @curious: given that I'm a lowly software engineer, it really isn't my place to say what physics undergrads or researchers should have to know about anything. I'll only add this: as others have remarked, intuitions are (clearly) very useful, as shortcuts to proofs or as teaching tools. In general, I don't feel as though mathematicians are rejecting or ostracising intuitions. In fact some of them are even glorified as "conjectures". Simply, it seems to me that they should always be treated with a sane amount of suspicion.

Comment: Sometimes intuitions are extremely hard if not impossible to share. You can tell someone the intuition about how to ride a bike all day long, they will never succeed on words alone. They themself have to try and fail and try and at some point succeed by using it on their own. The Definitions/Theorems/Lemmas are the bike here. Sometimes the intuition behind a Def./Theorem etc. can be told, but you have to use it to build the intuition for yourself. In my experience Mathematicians are always eager to tell you about their intuition about bike-riding if you ask them.

Comment: Most overview texts at least cover a decent amount of intuition. Some of "the resources" for a field often totally lack it. Not every text is designed to do the same thing. Some are meant just to be a resource to use after you understand the subject, some are meant to bring you into the subject. There are *plenty* of physics texts that don't do a great job with physical intuition, especially at the graduate level. You might have just avoided them.

Comment: Moreover, not every subject is really intuitive without a total shift in the way you think. Measure theory is not super intuitive the first time through the subject, maybe not even the second time. Abstract algebra is a big shift since most of what you know to that point is analysis-y or very integer/real number specific so more advanced results (Sylow and results about prime powers, etc) are less clear. Also keep in mind that math has been built up for centuries. Most of modern physics comes from the last $100$ years and change. There is a lot less to know, in a sense.

Comment: And specifically about modern physics, most of what is taught at the graduate level really falls between $1900$ish and $1960$ish. Mechanics and E&M being the main exceptions which find their roots in the $1800$s.

Comment: You're basically asking why mathematicians write books for mathematiicans. If you want a book full of applications, examples, history, and intuition of rigor, that's a perfectly things to read or write, but it's not as useful to the intended audience of most math books. You'll have better luck finding that sort of thing with more introductory textbooks; but even there the goal is to help the reader do math, which is all about the gory technical details.

Comment: This is just my interpretation, but it feels that often an "intuition" in such questions means something similar to "context" or "providing toy example, where the new concept/definition/theorem shines". The gory technical details are the bread and butter of any working mathematician, sure, but sometimes it seems that even few sentences, highlighting central ideas in the proof, could make that gore easier to grasp, to the point where it would appear natural. Of course I'm not saying that all math books should be written this way, but even introductory texts sometimes don't provide such info.

Comment: @CameronWilliams (In another forum) someone asked, what are the prerequisites for measure theory. The answers were, just basic set theory, unless you want to understand what it's about, in which case you need a lot more.

Comment: What you're describing is just the phenomenon that unfortunately many textbook authors are very bad at their jobs... however, is this really so different in physics? My very first encounter with the concept of "mathematical motivation" was self-studying physics as a teenager, when the textbook I was using completely failed to explain the motivation/intuition for the concept of torque and the formulae behind it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The question is a reasonable one. I think part of the issue is that there are secretly a few types of math texts and typically it's not clear which book is of which type.

1. Some are written for people who "already know the material" but need to either fill in minor gaps or have a reference for some proofs. These will typically be written concisely with not so much motivation, because the target audience would not need these things as much.
2. Some of them are written for the newcomer. These texts will typically have more filler text and background information. Often, they have sections discussing motivation and historical context. More often than not, these texts are directed at undergraduates.

---

**Opinion:** My personal opinion is that motivations are best learned from asking friends working in the respective fields, though I do think it is important to have these motivations written down in some places. However, it does seem that sometimes a little too much emphasis on carrying out the details of proofs is present in some math courses. I feel that the most precious information that a lecturer can impart is the *context* and *motivation* of a field - after all, the proofs are usually in many different books.

It can be quite important to understand historical context in learning math. For instance, it's easier to understand the definition of a "scheme" if you understand at least a little bit the classical theories that preceded schemes and what problems the definition was meant to address.

Answer (score 4):

Given that physics is all about converting physical problems into mathematical problems and the latter's solutions back into physical solutions, what you propose isn't in concert with physicists' true motive for introducing such intuitions. It's not about augmenting the opportunities for understanding that proofs provide. It's about several factors (which pure mathematics doesn't succumb to due to not being empirical). I'll present a by no means complete list:

- Helping us decide what the axioms should be in the first place, by reminding us of the real-world explanatory power we seek;
- Reminding us of the older physical theory we must improve upon;
- Identifying where the theory connects to something we can test against observation;
- Critiquing the current state of our understanding, either as the scientific community or students who haven't learned all the community knows, so we can direct future efforts, which will often involve theoretical refinements;
- Comparing the practical benefits of specific notations, calculation techniques etc.;
- Knowing which approximations our models should take in which regimes, especially where this explains qualitative phase changes in response to continuous changes around values either observation or calculation shows to be critical.